# KBinsDiscretizer for strings

Tags: python, pandas, scikit-learn, binning

[`KBinsDiscretizer`](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.preprocessing.KBinsDiscretizer.html) bins *numeric* data.

I have *string* data whole [`value_counts`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.value_counts.html) looks like this:

```
MTS RUS                   495
Tele2                     484
MegaFon                   437
Beeline                   431
Vodafone UA               402
                         ... 
3 Austria                   1
FJ VODAFONE | Vodafone      1
Babilon-M                   1
MOOV BENIN                  1
3 | Beeline                 1
Name: carrier, Length: 822, dtype: int64
```

This is already categorical, but there are far too many different values (822!).

I want to bin it to very few different values (5-10) with equal hight bins (like `strategy="quantile"` in `KBinsDiscretizer`).

The algorithm is very simple: apply `KBinsDiscretizer` to the data converted to numeric rank of the value in `value_counts`.

I wonder if there is already a method for it (and, if not, how to do it idiomatically).

PS. A critical constraint is that the approach must be "general purpose", I cannot examine *every* string column I have to optimize binning individually.

Answer (score 0):

Here is what I put togethers, it seems to work, but I wish I could use something OOTB:

```py
import sklearn
from sklearn.base import TransformerMixin, BaseEstimator

def only_column(df):
    if df.shape[1] != 1:
        raise ValueError("only_column",df.shape)
    return df[df.columns[0]]

class ObjectDiscretizer(TransformerMixin, BaseEstimator):
    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        self.kbin_discr = sklearn.preprocessing.KBinsDiscretizer(**kwargs)
        self.name2rank = None
        self.names = None
        self.ranks = None
    
    def __str__(self):
        if self.name2rank is None:
            return "%s(%s)" % (self.__class__.__name__, self.kbin_discr)
        return "%s(n=%d, b=%d, %s)" % (
            self.__class__.__name__, len(self.name2rank), 
            len(self.kbin_discr.bin_edges_), self.kbin_discr)

    def fit(self, X, y=None):
        "Learn how to discretize the data."
        col = only_column(X).astype(str)
        # np.unique does not always work
        # https://github.com/numpy/numpy/issues/18288
        vc = col.value_counts(dropna=False)
        self.name2rank = {v:i for i,v in enumerate(vc.index)}
        self.names, self.ranks = np.array(list(zip(*sorted(self.name2rank.items()))))
        self.kbin_discr.fit(col.replace(self.name2rank).values.reshape((-1,1)))
        return self
    
    def transform(self, X):
        "Discretize the data."
        return self.kbin_discr.transform(self.ranks[np.searchsorted(self.names, X.astype(str))]).astype(int)
```